# Encriptacion AES en java y Desencriptacion AES en c#

Tags: java, c#, android, webservice

espero que la pregunta no sea redundante, y puedan ayudarme.
Estoy creando una aplicación que pueda conectarse a un webservice. en la aplicacion pido un usuario y una contraseña las cuales debo encriptar con el algoritmo AES, estos datos encriptados llegan al webservice alojado en IIS, pero a la hora de desencriptar en el servidor me manda un error.
este es el codigo para encriptar en android

```
   String password="1234";
   String encode="UTF-8"; 
   String algoritmo="AES";

      private String encripta(String serie) throws Exception {
      Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance(algoritmo);
      SecretKeySpec secretKey= generatekey();
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey);
     byte[] datosencriptadosbytes=cipher.doFinal(serie.getBytes());
     String datosencriptadosstring= 
     Base64.encodeToString(datosencriptadosbytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
     return  datosencriptadosstring;
}
```

codigo que genera la key

```
 private SecretKeySpec generatekey() throws Exception {
    MessageDigest sha=MessageDigest.getInstance(sha_str);
    byte[] key=password.getBytes(encode);
    key=sha.digest(key);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(key,algoritmo);
    return  secretKey;
}
```

Esto es del lado del servidor

```
 public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
       byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
       byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
       byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456789ABCDEF");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (AesManaged AES = new AesManaged())
            {
                AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes,1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize/8 );
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize /8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
                }
                decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return decryptedBytes;
    }
```

y el error que me da es "el relleno entre caracteres no es válido y no se puede quitar" en visual studio, espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: Seguramente no sea esto, pero sólo para confirmar: ¿Antes de descifrar, has decodificado de Base64? Parece una tontería, pero puesto que esa parte está en el código Java pero no lo veo en el código c#, dudo

Comment: que tal, si, el metodo AES_Decrypt recibe como parametro los bytes de la cadena base 64

Comment: Hola. Puedes especificar el mensaje de error? El InnerException también ayudaría. Gracias

Comment: En la parte del servidor no estás deshaciendo BAse64 así que lo más probable es que te venga por ahí el fallo.

Comment: Yeltssin, buen dia pudiste resolver este caso, tambien tengo este problema que no puedo descriptiar en C# una cadena encriptada originada desde java, si lo resolviste me podrias orientar, para salir de esta, te lo agradecre Saludos.